# Setting values a Column's of third Table By Subtracting Two different columns of two different tables

Tags: c#, sql, database

I have  four tables named as "Product-table" ,"entry-table","exit-table" and "statistics".

Product-table contains columns(ProductID,Name,ProductType,Price)

entryTable contains Columns (ID,availableQuantity,date)

exit-Table contains Columns (ID,IssuedQuantity,Date)

Statistics table contains (ID,currentlyAvalibleIQuantity,Issued Quantity,Date)

"ID " column in entry-table, exit-Table, statistic table act as a primery key and foriegn key.==> "ProductID".

Now i want statistic table column values look like

currentlyAvailbleQuantity=AvailbleQuantity-IssuedQuantity;

IssuedQuantity=exitTable.IssuedQuantity;

is there  any  solution for this problem?

is it possible  automatically updation of statistics table.?

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: nothing. i have no idea

Answer (score 0):

For automatically updating the entries in statistics  table create a trigger for entry table and exit table when you are doing insert update and delete.

> create a procedure to get the availability and issues  by joining statistics   table and product table.